# scsi timing out command, waited 300 seconds

Tags: kernel, boot, devices, scsi

I am booting rescue system on a server, which has defective HDD or controller.

The kernel boot process times out with following messages:

```
scsi timing out command, waited 300 seconds
```

eventually it will boot, but it takes 10 minutes

How can I pass the kernel, as boot parameter, some shorter scsi timeout, perhaps 10 seconds ?

I am using kernel

Comment: If the device is known defective, what about simply disabling it via some appropriate libata.force kernel boot parameter ?